# JMeter Run - Thread count not same as thread count in logs

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

I am running JMeter test for 300VUs for 12 minutes. Set loop count as 1. Please refer below thread group info:

[image]

But why the total thread in green at upper right is not same as in the logs?

[image]

Here's the screenshot after finish the test run, still not same thread count.:

[image]

The thread count at upper right should be 300/300, not 0/300 right? Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) settings:

1. You defined "Loop Count" as `1`
2. You have 5 samplers
3. You have Ramp-up Period of 600 seconds
4. The above points mean that:

   - JMeter start a new thread each 2 seconds
   - the thread will start executing samplers upside down
   - when last sampler is done the thread will be shut down
5. The number of active threads will depend on application response time
6. If you want to reach 300 threads concurrency - set Loop Count to `Infinite` and make sure that test duration is larger than the ramp-up period

   More information: [JMeter Test Results: Why the Actual Users Number is Lower than Expected](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-test-results-why-actual-users-number-lower-expected)
7. Don't use GUI mode for tests execution, it's for test development and debugging only, the execution should be done using [command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
8. Remove all the listeners, they don't add any value but [consume valuable resources](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean)

Answer (score 0):

The number is the number of **current running** threads, so at the end of the tests it will be 0

Comment: Meaning not necessarily to be 300/300? coz if i run for infinite loop, it will be 300/300 after the thread lifetime ends. so is my working is already correct by this way?

Comment: @sabbyna it will show 300 threads until threads end, if you add ramp up times it won't be 300 at start

Comment: i also added the ramp up times, okay so i tried to run 1k users, ramp up 600secs, loop count infinite, thread lifetime 720 mins.  at 10 minutes, in the log it shows thread started: thread group 1-1000. then at minutes 12 (after test ends), i got several messages "stopping because end time detected by thread". this means all threads not finished at 12 minutes time?

Comment: @sabbyna JMeter try to stop all the threads, not all stop in the exact time